# Is it possible to have an Approval process dependent on a related list record?

Tags: administration, approval-process

I have an opportunity with a custom object "product__c" related list. I want to be able to send the opportunity for approval only if a record of "product__c" is added that has a certain field value, e.g., product_category__c = "diamond". I think that I am limited to creating an approval process on the "product__c" object directly however I would love to know am I wrong?Can I create an approval process on the opportunity object that looks at the related list record.

Comment: How about a trigger to populate the count on Object Opportunity and then based on Count Triggering the approval process .If you want to trigger automatically a trigger can be designed appropriately .

Comment: If the custom object is a master detail relationship, you could also use a roll up summary field too, to count the records that meet the criteria, then key your approval process from that.